# styling npm vuejs-paginate component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, pagination

I am using the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-paginate
to handle pagination in a vuejs application.

I would like to style this pagination component.
My styling successfully sets the background of page number buttons yellow when the user hovers over them, but fails to set the background of the current page to green. Why?

Here is my component tag with the props.

```
 <paginate
    :pageCount="totalPages"
    :click-handler="paginateCallback"
    :prevText="'Prev'"
    :nextText="'Next'"
    :containerClass="'pagination'"
    class="pagination"
    v-model="pageNumber"
  ></paginate>
```

And here is the css...

```
.pagination a {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
.pagination  a.active {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
.pagination  a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: yellow;}

.pagination   a:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  }

  .pagination a:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
```

By the way, in case it is relevant information, the application uses bootstrap-vue elsewhere.

Thanks to the first answer below, I was able to resolve this.
Here is the working css after adding the active-class prop to the component...

```
 .pagination li {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .pagination li.pagination-active {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
.pagination  li:hover:not(.active) {background-color: yellow;}
```

Now, however, there is a border around the number of the active page button until the user clicks again anywhere on the page. How can we eliminate this border?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentations](https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate#readme) says: there is an `active class` prop that you can set and style that class. see the props in the link above.

```
    <paginate
    :pageCount="totalPages"
    :click-handler="paginateCallback"
    :prevText="'Prev'"
    :nextText="'Next'"
    :active-class="myActiveBtn"
    :containerClass="'pagination'"
    class="pagination"
    v-model="pageNumber"
  ></paginate>
```

style:

```
.myActiveBtn{
  background-color: green;
 }
```

Comment: Okay. With your help and after debugging some css specificity bug, the button corresponding to the active page takes on the green background color.

Comment: I updated the question with a minor follow up question that I noticed after updating colors.